# Parsing FLV header (duration) of remote file in Java

Tags: java, python, flash, flv

I'm looking for an example of parsing an FLV header for duration specifically in Java. Given the URL of an FLV file I want to download the header only and parse out the duration. I have the FLV spec but I want an example. Python or PHP would be OK too but Java is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have problems downloading the header or parsing it? if it's downloading then use this code:

```
URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
InputStream dis = url.openStream();
byte[] header = new byte[HEADER_SIZE];
dis.read(header);
```

You can wrap InputStream with DataInputStream if you want to read int's rather than bytes.

After that just look at getInfo method from PHP-FLV Info or read the spec.

Comment: I had a combination of both. Since I've seen the spec though, the biggest question was the best way to download part of the file then parse the header. I experimented with sending the HTTP Range header to say how many bytes I wanted but only some servers send back HTTP 206 Partial Content so your solution is better.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, if you have questions about parsing, just edit the question.

Comment: InputStream.read does not necessarily read fully. For an easy solution, wrap in `DataInputStream` and call `readFully`.

Answer (score 0):

As [the-alchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423943/the-alchemist) states in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669109/how-to-get-flv-duration-in-java):

> The [Red5 project](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) has a class called
>   [`FLVReader`](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3847/java/server/branches/xuggle_timestamp_fixes/src/org/red5/io/flv/impl/FLVReader.java) which does what you want.
>   It's LGPL licensed.

I've tried it and it works fine. You'll need this libraries:

- [Red5 library jar for use when building applications](https://code.google.com/p/red5/downloads/list)
- [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi)
- [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/downloads.html)

Getting the FLV video duration is as simple as this:

```
FLVReader flvReader = new FLVReader(...); // Can use a File or a ByteBuffer as input
long duration = flvReader.getDuration();  // Returns the duration in milliseconds
```