# How to get flv duration in java?

Tags: java, parsing, flv

Given a flv file, **how do I get the video duration in java code?** That is, how to parse the flv header to get the video duration?

***Note:*** *I've found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313640/parsing-flv-header-duration-of-remote-file-in-java), but the answer is about getting the file header content from a given url and not about parsing that header.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Red5 project](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) has a class called [`FLVReader`](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3847/java/server/branches/xuggle_timestamp_fixes/src/org/red5/io/flv/impl/FLVReader.java) which does what you want.  It's LGPL licensed.